# How to check the histogram is correct or not in R?

Tags: r, histogram, probability, logarithm

I have a data frame D of probability values and try to plot the histogram of it. The histogram bellows are for those probability values and for -log10(D). However, the histogram -log10(D) looks wrong because it stops in around 3.5 in x axes. Why is this the case? This is the histogram for D.

[image]

and this if for -log10(D)

[image]

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(D)`, as well as the code you've used to generate the histograms.

Comment: It is difficult to give the reproducible dataframe I have. I just use hist(D) and hist(-log10(D)). The values for a dataframe D are from 0 to 0.9732063, respectively. Therefore, the minimum and maximum of -log10(D) are 0.01179509 and Inf, respectively

Answer (score 1):

Your vector D can be approximated with:

```r
set.seed(123)

D <- 10^(-sample(seq(0, 3.5, length = 1000), 
                 prob = seq(300, 1, length = 1000),
                 replace = TRUE))
```

And we can see the histogram looks similar, with an x axis range between 0 and 1:

```r
hist(D)
```

[image]

and the histogram of `-log10(D)` is also similar:

```r
hist(-log10(D))
```

[image]

The reason why the x axis stops at 3.5 is simply because you have no values in D that are smaller than `10^(-3.5)`, which is 0.0003162278

In my example, I get:

```r
min(D)
#> [1] 0.0003715952
```

which means that the maximum value of `-log10(D)` is less than 3.5:

```r
max(-log10(D))
#> [1] 3.42993
```

Comment: Actually, I do have.  The minimum and maximum values of D are 0 and 0.9732063, respectively. Therefore, the minimum and maximum of -log10(D) are  0.01179509 and Inf, respectively. I cannot give a reproducible output since it is a relatively large data frame. Your answer does make sense tho for your example.

Comment: @MKHuda obviously, you can't have infinite values on a histogram. What's your smallest non-zero value in D? `min(D[D>0])`?

Comment: I checked it and I got 0.0005928686, also -log10(0.0005928686) = 3.227042 so it is weird when I check using min() and max(0 function I got  0.01179509 and Inf, respectively. Does it mean that the highest positive value for -log10(D) is actually 3.227042 and therefore in the hist(-log10(D)) it stops in aroun 3.4 (without more bin on the right side after 3.227042)?

Comment: @MKHuda the infinite values are removed when you plot a histogram, so the highest -log10 you have left is 3.227042. I don't think that's weird at all.